# Declaring 2 similar anonymous objects

Tags: c#, .net

Below is the declaration of 2 anonymous objects. The second one is the exact same copy of the first one except there is no `lastRefresh` element inside it.

Is there a way to declare these 2 objects without duplicating the exact same portion?

```
var routeValuesForAutoRefresh = new
{
    page = @ViewBag.nextPage,
    lastRefresh = @ViewBag.lastRefresh,
    searchTerm = Request["searchTerm"],
    searchColumn = Request["searchColumn"],
    searchOrder = Request["searchOrder"],
    searchDescending = (Request["searchDescending"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus0 = (Request["requestStatus0"] ?? "false").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus1 = (Request["requestStatus1"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus3 = (Request["requestStatus3"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus5 = (Request["requestStatus5"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus7 = (Request["requestStatus7"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus9 = (Request["requestStatus9"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1
};
var routeValuesForNextPage = new
{
    page = @ViewBag.nextPage,
    searchTerm = Request["searchTerm"],
    searchColumn = Request["searchColumn"],
    searchOrder = Request["searchOrder"],
    searchDescending = (Request["searchDescending"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus0 = (Request["requestStatus0"] ?? "false").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus1 = (Request["requestStatus1"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus3 = (Request["requestStatus3"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus5 = (Request["requestStatus5"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus7 = (Request["requestStatus7"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus9 = (Request["requestStatus9"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1
};
```

Comment: Is there any harm in including `lastRefresh` in `routeValuesForNextPage`?

Comment: It seems like a XY problem, because since you're talking about routing, you should explain what you want to achieve and maybe your approach and even my own answer isn't *the answer*

Comment: can you make a use of method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax for it, but you have a couple of decent workarounds:

- Make your class named, and derive one from the other (or derive both from a common base)
- Make a third anonymous object with the common fields, then use it in both "real" named objects
- Make individual local variables, and use them to make fields of both anonymous objects.

I would prefer the first approach, but the other two approaches would be an improvement.

Here is an example of the second approach:

```
var routeValuesForNextPage = new
{
    page = @ViewBag.nextPage,
    searchTerm = Request["searchTerm"],
    searchColumn = Request["searchColumn"],
    searchOrder = Request["searchOrder"],
    searchDescending = (Request["searchDescending"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus0 = (Request["requestStatus0"] ?? "false").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus1 = (Request["requestStatus1"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus3 = (Request["requestStatus3"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus5 = (Request["requestStatus5"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus7 = (Request["requestStatus7"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1,
    requestStatus9 = (Request["requestStatus9"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1
};
var routeValuesForAutoRefresh = new {
    routeValuesForNextPage
,   lastRefresh = @ViewBag.lastRefresh
};
```

Here is an example of the third approach:

```
var page = @ViewBag.nextPage;
var searchTerm = Request["searchTerm"];
var searchColumn = Request["searchColumn"];
var searchOrder = Request["searchOrder"];
var searchDescending = (Request["searchDescending"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1;
var requestStatus0 = (Request["requestStatus0"] ?? "false").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1;
var requestStatus1 = (Request["requestStatus1"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1;
var requestStatus3 = (Request["requestStatus3"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1;
var requestStatus5 = (Request["requestStatus5"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1;
var requestStatus7 = (Request["requestStatus7"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1;
var requestStatus9 = (Request["requestStatus9"] ?? "true").ToLower().IndexOf("true") > -1;

var routeValuesForAutoRefresh = new {
    page,
    lastRefresh = @ViewBag.lastRefresh,
    searchTerm,
    searchColumn,
    searchOrder,
    searchDescending,
    requestStatus0,
    requestStatus1,
    requestStatus3,
    requestStatus5,
    requestStatus7,
    requestStatus9
};
var routeValuesForNextPage = new {
    page,
    searchTerm,
    searchColumn,
    searchOrder,
    searchDescending,
    requestStatus0,
    requestStatus1,
    requestStatus3,
    requestStatus5,
    requestStatus7,
    requestStatus9
};
```

Comment: The 2nd approach is perfect for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> My question: is there a way to declare these 2 objects without
>   duplicating the exact same portion ?

Of course, *using regular classes*.

Implement a class `RouteValues` which should contain shared properties and also implement derived classes which inherit `RouteValues` to add more properties.

If you're worried about having to set each property one by one using dot syntax (i.e. `values.whatever = "hello world";`), you can use *type initializers*:

```
RouteValues values = new RouteValues
{
    page = @ViewBag.nextPage
};
```